# playing a MP3 from raw folder?

Tags: android, button, android-mediaplayer

im trying to play a MP3 from raw folder .i have different buttons which playing different MP3's so i must change the mediaplayer input every time here is my code on button click:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        t=R.raw.virtualbarber
                playsound(t);

        }
```

and here is my mediaplayer code which im taking error in .create ! :

```
private void playSound(string t ){
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), t);
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

    mp.release();
}
}); 
mp.setLooping(true);
mp.start();
}}
```

im also declared my string and mediaplayer on top of my project like this :

```
MediaPlayer mp;
int t;
```

nothing works ! my other program worked correctly but this doesn't !

logcat

```
01-17 22:01:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(30521): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 22:01:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(30521): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.safshari.board3d/com.safshari.board3d.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 22:01:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(30521):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
01-17 22:01:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(30521):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
```

Comment: `v==R.raw.virtualbarber` is very not belonging. `R.id.something` is more pleasing.

Comment: then how can i add my mp3 to media player ?

Comment: i take the media player code from my other program it had just one mp3 and working correctly i want to add one for each button

Comment: `t` is not a string. R.raw.virtualbarber should be an `int`. So, `playSound(int t);` makes more sense.

Comment: @Soheyl `mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.virtualbarber);`

Comment: mediaplayer fixed tnx to you but now im getting nullpointer exception on start of program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.virtualbarber);
```

If it is fragment instead of `this` use `getActivity()`.

```
mediaplayer fixed tnx to you but now im getting nullpointer exception on start of program ?
```

If its still crashing post the updated relevant code along with stacktrace for further help

Comment: @Soheyl post the full stacktrace. there is a caused by part that is what indicates the line that caused the exception

Comment: ok ill fixed null pointer myself it was rookie problem ! so how i stop playing what was playing before so both mp3 cant play simultaneously ?

Comment: @Soheyl new problem post a new question with relevant details

Answer (score 0):

Use the uri something like:

```
  Uri myUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.package.sample/raw/filename");
  mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
  mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
  mp.prepare();
```